# Rust mapping wants me to put a block

Tags: rust

When working on a training problem for rust, I needed to take all items in a vector, square each of them, and then sum them. I realize that this is not good code and that changing it is faster than asking StackOverflow. I will be changing how this works but right now I'm just trying to learn how to use map and no examples seem to help me with this problem. This is for understanding, but if you have a more idiomatic way to code this quite simply, I would also love to see that. Here is the line of code:

```rust
let thing1 = divs.into_iter().map(|n| -> n*n).collect::<Vec<u64>>.iter().sum();
```

The important bit being:

```rust
divs.into_iter().map(|n| -> n*n)
```

Here is the error:

```rust
error: expected `{`, found `*`
  --> src/lib.rs:10:51
   |
10 |         let thing1 = divs.into_iter().map(|n| -> n*n).collect::<Vec<u64>>.iter().sum();
   |                                                   ^ expected `{`
   |
help: try placing this code inside a block
   |
10 |         let thing1 = divs.into_iter().map(|n| -> n{ *n }).collect::<Vec<u64>>.iter().sum();
   |                                                   +    +

error: could not compile `challenge` due to previous error
```

This error persists regardless of what operation I do on n, n+1, etc. I tried doing what the complier wanted and it thought I was trying to dereference n. I don't understand why map would act this way - all examples I've seen don't use blocks in map.

Comment: `|n| -> n*n` is invalid syntax for a closure - `->` is only used when specifying a return type. `|n| n*n` is the correct way to write this.

Comment: NIT: you are also missing the parenthesis when calling collect: `.collect::<Vec<u64>>()`. NIT: you don't need to `.collect()` and `.iter()` to call `.sum()`.

Answer (score 2):

You would only want to put `->` for a closure to denote the return *type*. `n*n` is not a type, so the compiler tries to guess that you meant `n` as the return type and `*n` as the closure body, which could be valid syntax if the braces are added.

Simply remove the `->`.